# Where do I retrieve model data in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

New to Xamarin Forms.

Data can be retrieved from services in many places during the navigational flow of an application:

- From the page that is navigated from and passed as parameters to the
  new page's constructor
- From the constructor of the new page
- From the OnAppearing method of the new page

Are there any established patterns for this?

Reason I'm asking is that currently I am retrieving data via REST in the page that I am navigating away from. It works but feels wrong. When I move my data access to the OnAppearing method of the page I am navigating to I get issues when navigating back.

Comment: Keep service call code out of the constructor since your service call code should be async and you mostly cannot call async methods in the constructor without using very bad patterns. I make my service calls in `OnAppearing()` mostly but sometime if there is a lot of data and it makes sense, I move it to the previous page. What kind of navigation issues?

Comment: Thanks for the advice and confirming to me that I am on the right track. I managed to sort out the issue with the back navigation (I wasn't guarding against a SelectedIndex of -1 on a Picker control in an event which fired after resetting the Picker's items)